# Conditionally Hiding the Place Order button in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using the plugin called Conditional Shipping and Payment however it still displays the place order button in the absence of a shipping method or payment method.

I am trying to hide the button or grey it out making it non-selectable if there is a lack of payment method or shipping options.

The checkout already says that there does not appear to be any available shipping or payment methods when i conditionally block the payment however i am still stuck this is what i have so far.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'place_order');

function hide_place_order($gateways) {

if($gateways == 'null' || 'null' === $rate->method_id ){

$style = 'style="background:Silver !important; color:white !important; cursor: not-allowed !important;"';

$button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );

$button = '<a class="button" '.$style.'>' . $button_text . '</a>';
}

return $button;
}

elseif ($gateways !== 'null' ||  $rate->method_id !== 'null') {

// Show Place order Button

return $button;

}
```

however this is not working & im unsure of where to proceed from here. The image i uploaded is the image of the cart and that red button is what i am trying to make disappear if there are no shipping or payment options.

Effectively the logic is that if the billing or shipping address != the predefined list of an allowable area then do not give these options at checkout which as you can see in the image works, however the button is still there and still creates an order despite there being no available shipping methods or payment methods for that particular order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the place order button if there are no available shipping methods or payment you can do like this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_place_order_button' );
function remove_place_order_button( $button_html ) {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() || ! WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
        $button_html = '';
    }
    return $button_html;
}
```

Add a style tag to the checkout page that sets the display property of the place order button to none. You can customize according to your needs.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'hide_place_order_button' );

function hide_place_order_button( $button_html ) {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() || ! WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
        $button_html = '<style>.woocommerce-checkout #place_order {display:none;}</style>';
    }
    return $button_html;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply kampit and it appears thats exactly what i need however when i add it to the functions.php file for the theme it still does not appear to make any changes. Whats even more odd is i tried changing the error text in the wp-pay file in woocommerce templates and it appears as though it as well is not being affected by that either.

Comment: Try set to 99, which means that the function will run after all other functions with lower priorities. `add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_place_order_button', 99 );`

Comment: that worked however it now throws " a critical error has occured in place of the button." and breaks the layout.

Comment: staging.weedmart.io

Comment: I'm adding style tag to the answer. Let me know.

Comment: That worked beautifully btw tyvm, bonus question if i may how do i get the shipping options to update based on the input in the billing & shipping address? Currently in the checkout if you look at the url i gave you you can type anything in the page but it wont update or change the shipping options in the checkout page.

Comment: You can use the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook to modify the available shipping rates based on the user's billing and shipping address.